# Determine the error that caused a redirect in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web form application. In the web.config associated with this application, I handle my custom error like so:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="error.aspx" />
```

When a user gets to the error.aspx page, I want to determine what error caused this page to get reached. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [Server.GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx) Method

```
Exception LastError;
String ErrMessage;

LastError = Server.GetLastError();

if (LastError != null)
   ErrMessage = LastError.Message;
else
   ErrMessage = "No Errors";

Response.Write("Last Error = " + ErrMessage);
```

Answer (score 6):

You get the exception object with the `GetLastError` method:

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
```

(Copied straight out of the code of our error page, which has logged several million errors so far... :)

Comment: I shall hope that you are referring to a site that has seen extensive use over a long period of time ;)

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Yes, we have about 300 request per second, so it's not so many of them that ends up in the log. :) Buggy spiders and buggy IE prefetch causes a lot of the errors. :P